¿Cómo reemplazar diferentes tipos de comillas en PHP? Error debido al carácter { en el resultado final
Necesito crear desde PHP un contenido para pasarlo a LaTeX. La idea es reemplazar los diferentes tipos de comillas por algo como esto: \textquote{contenido entre comillas}.
Para ello he intentado con preg_replace().
Este es el código:
$str = "Reemplanzando comillas: 'simples' y \"dobles\" y «latinas» e “inglesas”";
$pattern=["/'(.*?)'/",'/"(.*?)"/',"/«(.*?)»/","/“(.*?)”/"];
echo $str = preg_replace($pattern, "\\textquote{$1}", $str);

Pero me da el siguiente error:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting
variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in ...

El problema es el carácter {, el cual necesito en el resultado final. Si pruebo el código sin ese carácter, funciona.
¿Cómo podría resolverlo?
El resultado final esperado sería este:
Reemplanzando comillas: \textquote{simples} y \textquote{dobles} y \textquote{latinas} e \textquote{inglesas}


Si escapo el símbolo del $ con una barra invertida dentro del preg_replace me funciona y me devuelve Reemplanzando comillas: \textquote{simples} y \textquote{dobles} y \textquote{latinas} e \textquote{inglesas}.  Es decir, preg_replace($pattern, "\\textquote{\$1}", $str);

@masterguru es correcto. Por favor ponlo como respuesta. Gracias.

El uso de las comillas dobles "" en PHP, en este caso dentro del parámetro de sustitución de la función preg_replace(), fuerza que se interpreten las posibles variables que empiezan por $ como una posible variable de PHP, tal como se indica en el apartado Análisis de variables.
Las tres posibles soluciones que pueden solventar este problema serían:

El uso de comillas simples, para evitar esa interpretación y que la función lo reconozca como un parámetro propio del replacement de preg_replace:

echo $str = preg_replace($pattern, '\\textquote{$1}', $str);


Si se quieren usar comillas dobles, escapar el símbolo de $ mediante una barra invertida, para evitar que PHP la interprete como variable y no como parámetro del preg_replace:

echo $str = preg_replace($pattern, "\\textquote{\$1}", $str);


O bien, aún usando comillas dobles, cambiar el $ por una doble barra invertida \\ antes del número que interpreta la sustitución a realizar:

echo $str = preg_replace($pattern, "\\textquote{\\1}", $str);

